# Which macro is more exact? __TIME__ or __TIMESTAMP__?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have the following little program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   std::cout << "Time: " << __TIME__ << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Timestamp: " << __TIMESTAMP__ << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

which produces the following output:

[image: Time and Timestamp output]

As you can see, `__TIME__` has a quite big difference with `__TIMESTAMP__`, it is ***4 seconds ahead***.

Why does this happen? How can there be such a difference between the two times?

Even the program's build time was less than 4 seconds, so where does this difference come from?

Comment: What compiler do you use? Can't reproduce it: http://ideone.com/FTMM2Y

Comment: Visual C++ compiler, I'm sorry I tagged gcc, my mistake

Comment: Why can't people just read the documentation?! -.-

Comment: Ain't nobody got time for that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The two macros do entirely different things:

---

### GCC

> `__TIME__`
>
> This macro expands to a string constant that describes **the time at which the preprocessor is being run**. The string constant contains eight characters and looks like "`23:59:01`".
>   If GCC cannot determine the current time, it will emit a warning message (once per compilation) and `__TIME__` will expand to "`??:??:??`".

([source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html))

> `__TIMESTAMP__`
>
> This macro expands to a string constant that describes **the date and time of the last modification of the current source file**. The string constant contains abbreviated day of the week, month, day of the month, time in hh:mm:ss form, year and looks like "`Sun Sep 16 01:03:52 1973`". If the day of the month is less than 10, it is padded with a space on the left.
>
> If GCC cannot determine the current date, it will emit a warning message (once per compilation) and `__TIMESTAMP__` will expand to "`??? ??? ?? ??:??:?? ????`".

([source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html))

---

### Visual Studio

> `__TIME__`: **The most recent compilation time of the current source file**. The time is a string literal of the form *hh:mm:ss*.
>   `__TIMESTAMP__`: **The date and time of the last modification of the current source file**, expressed as a string literal in the form *Ddd Mmm Date hh:mm:ss yyyy*, where *Ddd* is the abbreviated day of the week and *Date* is an integer from 1 to 31.

([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx))

Comment: Ohhhhh this is interesting! Must be it!

Answer (score 0):

```
__TIME__
```

Time when the `script started compiling` according to the current locale.

```
__TIMESTAMP__
```

Date & time of the `last modification to the script file` according to the current locale.

Comment: 5.2.6? 5.2.7? What are you referencing there? What is this funny `${}` notation? Why did you write non-code in code formatting?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just copied it from documentation...that funny ${} is also copied.

Comment: What documentation? Cite your sources bro!

Comment: I just listed the problems.

Comment: You're still not citing any sources and you're still employing bizarre `formatting` to `text that is not code`!